# Заполнение одной формы в зависимости от другой

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<input class="payment-input" id="payment-input-wm" oninput = "YandexFunction()" type="number" placeholder="Дни" autocomplete="off" min="1" max="112">

<input type="text" name="paymentType" value="" id="info-wm">
<p id="info-wm"></p>
      <script>
      function YandexFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("payment-input-ym").value;
        document.getElementById("info-ym").innerHTML = 'Сумма: ' +  x * 5 + '₽';
      }

      </script>
```

как сделать так чтобы выводилось не в p а в input?

Comment: `document.getElementById("тут_айди_инпута").value = 'Сумма: ' +  x * 5 + '₽';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну то что у тя, два `ID` на это тебе уже намекнули, но сама проблема в том, что у тя `ID` не совпадают...  Видать, какая та буква кириллицей прописана...

```js
function YandexFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
  document.getElementById("y").value = 'Сумма: ' + x * 5 + '₽';
}
```

```html
<input class="payment-input" id="x" oninput="YandexFunction()" type="number" placeholder="Дни" autocomplete="off" min="1" max="112">

<input type="text" name="paymentType" value="" id="y">
```

```js
var x = document.getElementById("payment-input-wm");
var y = document.getElementById("info-wm");

x.addEventListener('input', () => y.value = `Сумма: ${x.value*5}₽`)
```

```html
<input id="payment-input-wm" type="number">

<input type="text" name="paymentType" value="" id="info-wm">
```